# How to get sender's email address in Rails email template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email

I have a Rails 4 based project with many mailers. Different mailers sents emails with different sender's email addresses.

How can I found sender's email address to use it in mail template? For example, I just want to  get next code working:

inside mailers' view:

```html
This mail sent from <%= message.sender.first %>!
```

I found that 'message' object present not in all emails. So, where I can get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Pass the sender to the mailer during the initialization, then in mailer assign sender to a instance variable and you will have sender available in your mailer view. Check out the Rails mailer guide for more info: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html